# CSS -- li background-color and color do not work

Tags: html, css

I want to set the `background-color` and `color` of `li`. When I inspect it, it shows the property is loaded, but it does not show effect on the page.

[image: chrome inspect result]

Anyones know the reason and how to solve it?

**Upadate**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hbs7hey/4/) But it looks quite different when I run on Chrome simulator:

[image: how it looks like in Chrome]

Comment: We need to see actual code, can you make a demo or mock-up to show us?

Comment: Please post your code, not a picture of your code.    The likeliest explanation for your problem is that you have other CSS not shown in this screenshot overriding the colors (probably styling on the `<a>` that's hiding the `<li>` behind it), but there's no way for us to be sure from looking at a screenshot.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddler for that? Maybe style for `<a>` overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the `li` except an `a` which (presumably) has been styled to have its own colour.

Answer (score 0):

I add one more `a`, then problem solved.